# How would you Open PDFs Stored on Your iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I am creating an application that downloads one of its screens as PDF and stores it in a location such as  /var/mobile/Applications/B19F4B52-F19B-46F8-9CE0-FA4D4656367B/Documents/SecondScreen1.pdf.. I have no idea what this location is and i want to open this pdf later as well.. Meaning I want the user to be able to easily access his PDFs etc. Which means storing it in a location that is accessible to him. I'd like to know how i can direct a path or manage to store it in some other applications storage (such as photos or so).. Currently this is where i am storing the file i need to store.. -

```
 NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only store it in your apps sandboxed file hierarchy. The documents folder is usually the recommended one for files that should be exchangeable (to access via iTunes eg). But you can create your own directory too. you can't access other apps file structure. You could use iCloud or Dropbox I suppose.

But to make it accessible to the user, I would store it in documents as you did and enable iTunes file exchange. Also you could easily create a mail composer to send your PDF as email.

Comment: Thank You that was quite helpful. I have enabled itunes file exchange on the plist but how exactly would the user find the file?

Comment: Connect device to iTunes and select your app in the app-tab. The files contained in documents directory all show up then.